# Laravel Fractal Eager Loading

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

I'm using Laravel 5.3 with [Laravel Fractal](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal). I'm building a forum so when I want to receive all forums I do that like this:

```
$forums = Forum::with('messages', 'messages.user')
            ->latest()
            ->paginate(10);

        return fractal()
            ->collection($forums)
            ->transformWith(new ForumTransformer())
            ->paginateWith(new IlluminatePaginatorAdapter($forums))
            ->respond();
```

Then in ForumTransformer I'm doing this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jenssen\Forums;

use League\Fractal;

class ForumTransformer extends Fractal\TransformerAbstract
{
    public function transform(Forum $forum)
    {
        return [
            'id'                => $forum->id,
            'slug'              => $forum->slug,
            'name'              => $forum->name,
            'total_messages'    => $forum->messages->count(),
            'message_user'      => $forum->messages->first()->user->name . ' ' . $forum->messages->first()->user->last_name,
            'created_at'        => $forum->created_at,
            'updated_at'        => $forum->updated_at
        ];
    }
}
```

Is this a `n+1` problem? Or does Laravel use the eager loaded relationship in the ForumTransformer class?

Comment: So... What is the error message or the unexpected behaviour?

Comment: No error message. Just wondering if fractal is making the query's again for getting the messages and the user. Or does it use the already eager loaded information?

Comment: Oh, didn't knew there was **a** [`n+1` problem](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/n_plus_one/), sorry. At first read I thought you lacked an error message between the code and the "Is this [supposed lacking error above] a `n+1` problem?". All I've found about is [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), but I can't assure you that it is used in the ForumTransformer as you'd like to know...